# Different Basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Let $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_d\}$ be an orthonormal system. Consider the canonical basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_d\}$.

It is given that $u_2^Te_1 = 0, \cdots, u_d^Te_1 = 0$.(That is all vectors $u_2,\cdots,u_d$ are perpendicular to $\underbrace{(1,0,\cdots,0)}_{d}$). What is the probability that $$\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_d\}$$ is a permutation of the canonical basis vectors.

Note that for $d=2$ this probability is $1$

For general $d$ the number of free variables that the $d^2$ components in $\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_d\}$ is $(d^2/2-3d/2+1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability is zero.

Take for example $d = 3$, and take

$u_1 = e_1$

$u_2 = (0, \cos \theta, \sin \theta) $

$u_3 = s (0, -\sin \theta, \cos \theta) $

where $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi ) s \in \{1, -1\} $

If $s = 1$ and $\theta = 0 $ then $u_2 = e_2 , u_3 = e_3$.  If $ s= -1$ and $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ then $u_2 = e_3, u_3 = e_2 $.  For all other values of $\theta$ and $s$, $u_2, u_3$ are not a permutation of $e_2, e_3$.  Hence the probability is zero.

Comment: Is there any further constraint that one can put to ensure probability is more than 0?